# What exactly is recorded in the transaction Logs?

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please explain **what is recorded in the transaction log?**

Along with the Data Modification operations what else is recorded in
the Transation-Log?

**Can you also tell me the why do we need the Transaction Logs?**

Comment: See [How to read the SQL Server Database Transaction Log](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Transaction Log Files are responsible for storing all the transactions that are executed against the database. The transaction log records every change that occurs within a database to persist all transactions to disk.
>
> **Many types of operations are recorded in the transaction log.**
>
> **These operations include:**
>
> 1. The start and end of each transaction.
> 2. Every data modification (insert, update, or delete).
>    This includes changes by system stored procedures or data definition language (DDL) statements to any table, including system
>    tables.
> 3. Database Name.
> 4. Object Name.
> 5. Transaction Name i.e. DML / DDL.
> 6. Whether the Transaction is committed or not committed.
> 7. Timestamp.
> 8. Transaction ID: is the ID of the transaction to which it belongs to.
> 9. Log Sequence Number of the Transaction.
> 10. Before and After Images are also recorded in the Transaction Log.
> 11. Rollback Operations are also recorded in the Transactin-Log.
> 12. Every extent and page allocation or deallocation.
> 13. Creating or dropping a table or index.

I hope this give you all those details for which you are looking.

**Answer to your Second Question: (Why do we need transaction log is as follows:)**

> **Purpose of Transaction Logs**
>
> - Recovery of individual transactions
> - Recovery of all incomplete transaction
> - Restore to the point of failure
> - Supporting Transactional replication.
> - Supporting high availability and disaster recovery solutions: AlwaysOn Availability Groups, database mirroring, and log shipping.

Comment: This is what exactly I was looking for.

Comment: Can you also tell me the why do we need the Transaction Logs?

Comment: Purpose of Transaction Logs
⦁ Recovery of individual transactions
⦁ Recovery of all incomplete transaction
⦁ Restore to the point of failure
⦁ Supporting transactional replication.
⦁ Supporting high availability and disaster recovery solutions: AlwaysOn Availability Groups, database mirroring, and log shipping.